# Derivation of negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y$ be geometric distribution where $ \mathbf P(X=k) = \mathbf P(Y=k) = (1-p)p^{k-1}$ for $k = 1, 2, 3...$

Using the convolution formula:

$$\mathbf P(Z=z)=\sum_{n=1}^{z-1} \mathbf P(X=z) \mathbf P(Y=z-n) = (z-1)((1-p)^2p^{z-1})=p(z-1)((1-p)^2p^{z-2})= p{z-1 \choose 2-1}(1-p)^2p^{z-2}$$

I don't know whether this correct or not, but it is different from the formula given on wikipedia which is given by (where $r$ is number of failures until experiment is stopped):

$$\mathbf P(X=k) = {k+r-1 \choose k}(1-p)^rp^k$$

And letting $r = z$ and $k=2$ as we have addition of 2 geometric random variables:
$$\mathbf P(X=2) = {z-1 \choose 2}(1-p)^zp^2$$

It looks similar but I don't know where I went wrong, why isn't it the same as what I have derived above?

Comment: See $2+z-1=z+1$

Comment: Your choice of Geometric RV models number of trials till the first success.  There is an alternate version for modelling the number of failures before the first success. $P(X=k) = (1-p)^kp$ for $k=0,1,2 \ldots$

Comment: Hint: Let $r=2$ and $k=z$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two distributions called Geometric.

### 1. The distribution of Bernoulli *trials until* a failure.

( This is sometimes called the *Shifted Geometric Distribution*. )

Assuming: $Z=X+Y$ and $\mathsf P(X=k)=\mathsf P(Y=k)=(1-p)p^{k-1}, k\in \{1,2...\}$ then

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Z=z) & = \sum_{k=1}^{z-1} \mathsf P(X=k)\mathsf P(Y=z-k) & \text{Note the summation bounds}
\\ & = \sum_{k=1}^{z-1} (1-p) p^{k-1}\cdot(1-p)p^{z-k-1}
\\ & = \sum_{k=1}^{z-1}(1-p)^2 p^{z-2}
\\ & = (z-1)(1-p)^2 p^{z-2}
\end{align}$

### 2. The distribution of Bernoulli *successes before* a failure.

Assuming: $Z=X+Y$ and $\mathsf P(X=k)=\mathsf P(Y=k)=(1-p)p^{k}, k\in \{0,1,2...\}$ then

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Z=z) & = \sum_{k=0}^{z} \mathsf P(X=k)\mathsf P(Y=z-k)
\\ & = \sum_{k=0}^{z} (1-p) p^{k}\cdot(1-p)p^{z-k}
\\ & = \sum_{k=0}^{z}(1-p)^2 p^{z}
\\ & = (z+1)(1-p)^2 p^{z}
\end{align}$

Which corresponds to the Negative Binomial distribution of parameters $p$ and $r=2$, which is that of a count of Bernoulli *successes before* the second failure.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Z=k) & = \binom{k+2-1}{k}(1-p)^2p^k
\end{align}$